# tf.gradients loads heavily RAM

Tags: tensorflow

I created an autoencoder model for CIFAR10 using tf.gradients in the following way:

```
W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([dimensionality, code_size], stddev=0.1))
b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[code_size]))
b_r = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[dimensionality]))

code_data = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(training_data, W) + b)
recover = tf.matmul(code_data, tf.transpose(W)) + b_r
grad_phi_psi = []
for i in range(batch_size):
    for j in range(dimensionality):
        grad_phi_psi.append(tf.gradients(recover[i][j], [training_data[i]], unconnected_gradients='zero')[0])
grad_phi_psi = tf.reshape(tf.stack(grad_phi_psi), [batch_size, dimensionality, dimensionality])
```

The loop there takes a lot of time and fills almost the whole 64Gb RAM, though I have only batch_size=10, dimensionality=3072

After it goes through model formation and session is initialized, it turns out that it uses only 250Mb GPU memory, but works very slow. RAM is still full.

What is the reason for such a heavy load on RAM. Can this be resolved somehow, cause I need to increase batch_size?